# OpenCV "findContours" method errors

Tags: c++, opencv

I was having issues with OpenCV 2.4.8's "findContours" method. Specifically the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats ([Start]FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images) in cvStartFindContours, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 196
```

From the contents of the message it would seem that I am using an inappropriate image format, however I'm *pretty sure* that my code specifies an 8uC1 (8 bit 1 channel) matrix.

```
/* Threshold source image (src1 which is a grayscale image) */
Mat threshImg(src1.rows, src1.cols, CV_8UC1);
threshold(src1, threshImg, thresh, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

/* Get contours */
Mat threshCopy = threshImg; // Copying image because findContours method edits image data
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(threshCopy, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0,0));
```

I am compiling the code on the command line using cl and link as follows:

```
$: cl NameOfCode.cpp -W2 -EHsc -c -I OpenCVIncludeDirectory
$: link NameOfCode.obj -LIBPATH:OpenCVLibraryDirectory opencv_core248.lib opencv_highgui248.lib opencv_imgproc248.lib
```

To enable the usage of cl and link I run vsvars32.bat from Visual studio 2010:

```
$: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
```

Comment: what's src1 ? if *that* is not CV_8UC1, but CV_8UC3 your threshold img won't be, too. (and no, you don't have to initialize it)

Comment: also, if you want a *copy* of the thresholded image, use: Mat threshCopy = threshImg.clone(); // your version only does a 'shallow' copy

Comment: @berak Thank you for the insight on using the clone() method. Also I might have been improperly loading src1. Now I am using 'Mat src1 = imread("PathToFile.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);' My code is no longer giving me an error message but it is still crashing with the general message _programName.exe has stopped working_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem ended up being Visual Studio related. After installing SP1 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691 and making adjustments to the code as suggested by berak and vasan. The final code is below:

```
/* NOTE: Using namespace cv & std */

/* Get input image */
Mat origImg = imread("C:\\PathToImage\\Image.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

/* Threshold input image */
Mat threshImg;
threshold(origImg, threshImg, 150, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY);

/* Get contours from threshold image */
Mat copyImage = threshImg.clone();
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(copyImage, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'm rewrite your code,I think it fine you can try it.**

```
//Copy the src1 image to threshImg
Mat threshImg = src1.clone(); 
//Covert the threshImg from 8-channel to 1-channel and threshold it to binary image.
cvtColor(threshImg,threshImg, CV_RGB2GRAY); 
threshold(src1, threshImg, thresh, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
//Finnaly you can get a contours.
Mat threshCopy = threshImg.clone;
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(threshCopy, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0,0));
```